# Configuring ActiveMQ transport

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I have an ActiveMQ JMS broker exposed with the default openwire TCP transport on port 61616.

I have numerous remote clients that with to bind to this broker to listen for their messages.

If I want to turn the keepAlive setting on, where do I need to configure it? On the broker (server-side) or for each client? Or both?

Or does configuring the broker to have tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?keepAlive=true, mean that any client connecting on tcp://<>:61616 will automatically inherit the keepAlive=true???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TCP KeepAlive option must be turned on at both client and broker side of the connection.  KeepAlive though is generally pretty useless as its default check interval is around 2 hours.

The [openwire protocol](http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-wire-formats.html) that activemq uses has its own heart beat functionality that is enabled by default and the configuration options are listed on the included link.  The client and broker will exchange heart beats every 30 seconds unless otherwise configured or disabled.